# How to parse a string in command line format in golang

Tags: go, command-line

I have some command line strings:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.avi
ffmpeg -i "my input.mp4" output_2.api
```

I'd like to parse them to slice: [ffmpeg, -i, input.mp4, output.avi] and [ffmpeg, -i, "my input.mp4", output_2.avi]. Is there any stable way to do that?

Comment: The stdlib doesn't provide anything special for the syntaxes used by various shells and asking from external libraries is OT on SO.

Comment: You could try [`shlex`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/shlex?tab=doc).

Comment: You could utilize `encoding/csv`, setting the `Comma` field to the empty space rune, something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/0b57oPG9QPD If the original string can have more than one space between the elements you'll need to additionally range over the slice and remove empty strings. This will work with the two inputs you've provided in the question however this is not a universal solution and will most probably break on a bit more complex input.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/shlex seems meet my requirement, I'll try it :)

Thanks very much for your support!

-- Klaus